# Using elasticsearch in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to use the Java API of elasticsearch. I can find many examples on how to use different elasticsearch methods but I am still stuck on how to set up elasticsearch so it is available within Java. I tried following this guide:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-use-elasticsearch-java-apps/index.html

So I set up a maven project in Eclipse and edited the POM.xml to include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In a main file I tried initializing a client using the TransportClient class. But it can't be resolved. It seems like my main doesn't know the elasticsearch types. What can I do about this?

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Eclipse or IDEA IntelliJ?  Please make sure your IDE can auto import Maven dependencies first.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your pom.xml you should rebuild your project. Maven will download the lib and normally you should than be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your maven project, go to `Maven -> Update Project` to update your maven. Then, your refresh your Project.

Another way to refresh your Maven Project is to run Maven clean install. 
`Run as -> Maven build` 
then fill `clean install` in the Goals edit box.